# Is there any way to visualize .grl extension grammar?

Tags: go, grammar, rule-engine

I'm studying rule engine for golang and came across a project on [github](https://github.com/hyperjumptech/grule-rule-engine) which is based on ANTLR4. I wish to visualize the grammar they're using (.grl extension). Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

[ANTLR Development Tools](https://www.antlr.org/tools.html) Page give you lots of options to help you visualize ANTLR4 grammar file. Most of them (if not all) are in form of IDE plugins. As the developer or grule, I use Goland plugin (same with Intellij) to develop Grule's grammar.